# Sum of a darboux function and a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

Could someone find an example where the sum of a darboux function and a continuous function is no longer darboux(have intermediate value property)?

I am given to understand this is possible in my class, but I couldn't verify the claim.

My best attempt so far is to pick a strongly darboux function with a special construction to allow me to "eliminate" in some finite interval, with a continuous function, a certain value in the range (i.e. making the inverse image of a point in R no longer dense), but I couldn't figure out what this construction may look like.

So also could someone tell me whether my direction is correct?

Thanks！

Comment: See this [3 December 2010 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7321228) and the google search for ["Darboux function" + "continuous" + "sums of"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Darboux+function%22+%22continuous%22+%22sums+of%22).